# Logistic Regression as Data Transform

Tags: probability

I have a small dataset with 2 continuous predictors, 3 nominal predictors, and one binary outcome.   Running logistic regression in matlab gets a non-significant result for all the predictors.

BUT if you use the fitted model to generate a probability for each observation (i.e., 'mnrval' in matlab, 'predict' in R), and then plot probability against each of the predictor variable levels, you see a good visual pattern, probability virtually linear with one of the continuous variables, and one of the nominal variables separating the observations into clumps.

Wondering how to get this visual effect to show up statistically, I ran a vanilla n-way ANOVA on the probabilities, and it "worked":  A main effect of continuous variable 1, a main effect of nominal variable 1, and a significant interaction of the two.

The probabilities are approximately normally distributed so this seems like a powerful way to transform data into a format where one can use anova which is more powerful than logistic regression.

But is it kosher?  Thanks for any thoughts.

Michael

Comment: How is this different from using simple regression to fit a straight line to some data and then finding that all predicted values lie on a straight line?

Comment: I'm not sure where you heard that "anova is more powerful than logistic regression" as it ain't true.  (And it's not the other way around either.  These are simply two different models that have different data requirements.)  And just hunting for statistical significance is not recommended.  This question would be better addressed at http://stats.stackexchange.com.  It might very well be that using logistic regression and transformations of your predictor variables might make for a better predictor.

Comment: @HansEngler  Logistic regression takes 0 or 1 for each observation and builds a model. Running the model returns a probability for each observation.   If its output was 0 or 1 for each observation, that would be analogous.

Comment: @JimBaldwin - Thanks for the pointer to stats.stackexchange.com.   I've advised my client that "just hunting for statistical significance is not recommended" and that he should replicate his research with a larger sample.  To answer your question about 'power' of LR versus Anova, I've seen it many places, and here is just one (with a quote):

Comment: Ran out of space.  Here is the ref:  http://www.statisticssolutions.com/assumptions-of-logistic-regression/ which states "... LogReg requires quite large sample sizes ... maximum likelihood estimates are less powerful than ordinary least squares (e.g., simple linear regression, multiple linear regression); whilst OLS needs 5 cases per independent variable in the analysis, ML needs at least 10 cases per independent variable, some statisticians recommend at least 30 cases for each parameter to be estimated."

Comment: Thanks.  Logistic regression does typically require larger sample sizes than ordinary linear regression but because there is no common objective stating that one approach is more powerful than another doesn't make a whole lot of sense.  I would run to stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Michael - my point is that fits from a regression (logistic or otherwise) always look nice, both to the naked eye and to statistical procedures, merely by design.